# How to SELECT part of records from a SQL table

Tags: sql, presto

Hi Have a table which contain more than 3 millions records(rows). So I want to select them like 1st, 2nd, 3rd .... 5 lacks of records. How can I do this.

Comment: use `limit` and `offset`.

Comment: In general, you do not want to do this in an analytics database.  To consistently give you "paged" results, the database must establish a total ordering, and then give you chunks of the ordered data.  In a single instance database like MySQL or PostgreSQL, this is easy, but in a distributed database, the engine typically does a total ordering for every single query.  Instead, you should either move the data to another system or cache the full dataset in your application.  In Hive, you could just download the raw files to do paging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presto, MySQL and PostgreSQL support the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` keywords so you can get the "pages", like

```
SELECT * FROM table [ ORDER BY ... ] OFFSET 1000 LIMIT 1000
```

will give you the 2nd group of 1000 records. 
The `ORDER BY` part is optional, but without explicit ordering, second "page" or results can be anything, even the same as the first "page" (this can be observed in practice in various databases).

Note: `OFFSET` is not necessarily the best way of paging results. Even though databases generally support `OFFSET`, [use it judiciously](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset).

Presto [supports `OFFSET` since Presto 311](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/release/release-311.html).
Before that version, Presto had `LIMIT` but no `OFFSET`, so
you would need to order by a value you can use as the "page size", like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > <<last-seen-id>> ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1000
```

`<<last-seen-id>>` would be the highest id value you've seen already in the set of 1000 records, and you have to keep updating it for each "page".
This is actually [the recommended approach](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page) even in databases that support `OFFSET` natively.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure about your question is proper understood or not but you can use something like this

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` LIMIT 10 OFFSET 100
```

10 is starting point

100 is limit (get total number of record as per your requirement)

Answer (score 0):

I have set 10 rows at a time. You can set according to yours.

You can try this:

For 1st 10 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName LIMIT 10 OFFSET (1-1)*10
```

For 2nd 10 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName LIMIT 10 OFFSET (2-1)*10
```

For 3rd 10 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName LIMIT 10 OFFSET (3-1)*10
```

For nth 10 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName LIMIT 10 OFFSET (n-1)*10
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

In MSSQL new version you can do Pagination.

See below Code for your reference.

```
Declare
@PageNumber INT = 1,
@PageSize   INT = 100

SELECT Column1, Column2,Column3 
    FROM dbo.[TableName]
    ORDER BY Column1
    OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: I use PrestoDB.